# Laravel / SQL - Storage data by time intervals

Tags: mysql, database-design

I've a series of events running for a couple months - events which happens every 3 days - that people can sign up for.

My original thought was to create tow individual tables, one to setup the intervals of time and the other to assign people's registration to a given period.

Then I could easily match the current day to one of these periods and list the results afterwards accordingly.

```
table 1. period_id, start_day, end_day
table 2. first_name, last_name, period_id
```

However this seems to lack some flexibility in the sense that a date change would simply affect the whole intervals of data.

Would there be a better or more efficient way to organize such data? I've also think about create just one table and work through code logic the initial date and figure out 3 days intervals from there... but that would seem to cause even more troubles when trying to organize and pull results together.

Comment: What should happen instead?

Comment: What `SELECTs ` will you have?